# Using a model in the controller for a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have a User model (generated by devise) and a Submission model in a Rails project. I've added a field called 'full_name' to the user model. Also, there is a field for 'user_id' in the submission model.

I want to show the the full_name of the user associated with the submission on the submission show page. Right now it shows the user_id from the submission model just fine.

The User model I have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :full_name, :role_id

  validates_presence_of :full_name
end
```

This is the model for submissions:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :user_id
end
```

This is in the controller:

```
  def show
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[@submission.user_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @submission }
    end
  end
```

What I get when I try to use this line in the view:

```
<%= @user.full_name %>
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

I've tried several variations and can't quite figure out what should be in the place of:

```
@user = User.find(params[@submission.user_id])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're populating the data correctly, you only need the following once you have looked up the submission.

`@submission.user`

If you think that the data is OK, then try the following in the Rails console.

`> Submission.first.user`

What do you see there?

---

The specific error that you are seeing is because this:

`params[@submission.user_id]`

is unlikely to ever have anything in it. If the user ID is "1" (for example) then you're asking for the value in the `params` hash that corresponds to the key "1".

Comment: It's a problem with my data. Thanks for suggesting looking in the console. The first User in my database has the id of 3 and the user_id in the submission has value of 1. When I change the user_id in the data to 3 and change the view to read: @submission.user.full_name instead it works. Thanks!